# How to create Android apps using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi

I have been asked to research on how to make an android app using Delphi, Now I am not sure that this can be done. I have not come across tutorials on the same. Somebody please clarify on this issue.

Comment: As of Oct/2013 the answer to this question is different. Take a look at the android code examples with Delphi: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/android-code-samples-xe5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<strike>Delphi cannot create Android apps at present. This is being worked on for a future release.</strike>

**Update:** As of the release of XE5, Delphi now supports Android development for certain ARM hardware using the mobile Delphi compiler.

Comment: The newly released RADPHP product supports Android when developing webapps, though.

Comment: @Remy That's not Delphi though is it? None of the other answers talk about things that are Delphi.

Comment: No, it is not Delphi, but it is the only Embarcadero product that supports developing code that runs in Android, albeit server-code code that runs from a webbrowser.

Comment: It seems unlikely that anyone has a particular desire just to use Embarcadero products!

Comment: The OP does, hense the question: "how to make an android app using Delphi"

Comment: The OP has expressed no such desire. The desire is to use Delphi. I use Delphi, but that fact makes me no more likely to select Emba's other language offerings, should I have the need.

Comment: Delphi XE5 supports Android development now. http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi

Answer (score 6):

Free Pascal is [now able to produce code for the Java platform](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_JVM) - so it might be feasible to create Delphi code which can be compiled to Java bytecode with FPC and then converted for the Dalvik VM.

> The FPC backend for the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) generates Java byte
>   code that conforms to the specifications of the JDK 1.5 (and later).
>   While not all FPC language features work when targeting the JVM, most
>   do (or will in the future) and we have done our best to introduce as
>   few differences as possible.
>
> This FPC JVM backend is not related to Project Cooper by RemObjects,
>   nor does FPC now support the Oxygene language.

Comment: Free Pascal's JVM bytecode stuff is experimental at best. However FPC has native Android support that is slightly further along. It is clumsy, but those are mostly Android limitations.

Answer (score 5):

Two choices to follow at present - check out Delphi for Android which is in design/beta phase: http://lenniedevilliers.blogspot.com/

Or, use Prism http://www.embarcadero.com/products/prism  (and check out their Oxygen for Java coming soon http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/java.aspx which is in Beta)

Comment: Delphi for Android cannot be used for real-life app development. And it seems (already) abandoned.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use a combination of Delphi, Sencha and PhoneGap by leveraging the Raudus framework. You can try the RaudusEmployee.apk example on your phone and see if this method will work for you.

http://www.raudus.com/samples/

This is not a native application, but similar to many new HTML5 applications.

Answer (score 4):

With [DWS](http://delphitools.info/dwscript/) as backend script compiler and the soon to come [Smart Mobile Studio (aka OP4JS)](http://op4js.optimalesystemer.no/about/) component library and RAD interface it will be possible to make apps running with HTML5 in android applications (and iOS or any other html5 compatible system).

By using object pascal, all Delphi and freepascal users will have a short learning curve and a high code reuse factor.

There are some samples using only the DWS backend here :

[taming-the-flock-with-object-pascal](http://delphitools.info/2011/09/28/taming-the-flock-with-object-pascal/)

[taming-html5-verlets-with-object-pascal](http://delphitools.info/2011/09/19/taming-html5-verlets-with-object-pascal/)

Update :
More samples can now be found on their homepage.

Answer (score 4):

First steps with native Android applications made with Lazarus/FPC are [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Android_Interface).

Answer (score 4):

Delphi XE5 is now released with Android support.

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/create-android-apps

Comment: It supports Android, iOS, Windows and OS X now.